# Performing an action after a test suite has finished running in XCTest

Tags: objective-c, swift, xcode, xctest, xctestcase

I need to make an API call after all the tests in my test suite has finished running. I'm aware of the method `testSuiteDidFinish(_ testSuite: XCTestSuite)`, this method does get called after a test suite execution, however it gets called as many times as the number of test cases I have.  In my test suite I have three test cases. I've added an observer to the test class. In my observer class, this is what I have:

```
public func testSuiteDidFinish(_ testSuite: XCTestSuite) {
   print("done")
}
```

"Done" gets printed three times after the execution of three tests. Why is doing so?

Comment: @Andrea Mugnaini, I usually just run the test classes corresponding the modules of the app which I want to test. I don't run the entire test bundle. testSuiteDidFinish does the job except that it's getting called multiple times :( I tried adding a testBundleDidFinish method in my observer class like you said, however it's not called when I run the tests in a test class.

Comment: Please show how you are creating and registering your observer. Also, print `testSuite.name`

Comment: This is my observer class: public class UITestObserver: NSObject, XCTestObservation {static var result = 1
    
    
    
    public func testCase(_ testCase: XCTestCase,
                         didFailWithDescription description: String,
                         inFile filePath: String?,
                         atLine lineNumber: Int){
            UITestObserver.result = 5
    }
    
    
    public func testSuiteDidFinish(_ testSuite: XCTestSuite) {

        print(testSuite.name)

    }

Comment: Test Suite 'LoginTests' passed at 2018-01-22 12:57:36.092.
  Executed 2 tests, with 0 failures (0 unexpected) in 79.535 (79.541) seconds
LoginTests
LoginTests
Test Suite 'FreshteamUITests.xctest' passed at 2018-01-22 12:58:48.465.
  Executed 2 tests, with 0 failures (0 unexpected) in 79.535 (151.915) seconds
FreshteamUITests.xctest
FreshteamUITests.xctest
Test Suite 'Selected tests' passed at 2018-01-22 12:58:55.098.
  Executed 2 tests, with 0 failures (0 unexpected) in 79.535 (158.550) seconds
Selected tests
Selected tests

Comment: I don't understand..the breakpoint at print(testSuite.name) gets paused multiple times...four I believe. First it prints 'LoginTests' , the actual name of my test suite , and then 'Selected Tests'. Each of them get printed twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function below works fine for what I was trying to achieve:

```
override class func tearDown() { 
   }
```

Whatever is written within it gets called only once, after my tests when a test class finishes executing.